# Negative aspects of dark color scheme (dark background with light text)

Tags: wpf, user-interface, color-scheme

I am using [Light on dark color scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-on-dark_color_scheme) in my WPF application.
My question is what are the negative aspects of this color scheme and why this color scheme is not widely used?

### Please follow this thread at [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/negative-and-positive-aspects-of-dark-color-scheme-dark-background-with-light-te)

Comment: You might have better luck on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is on topic here, but it might get better answers from UI developers at [ux.se].  Also, light on dark is hard to read and annoys the crap outta me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Darker color scheme are often used effectively in software that focuses heavily on visual content.** For example Adobe Lightroom, Adobe After Effects, Microsoft Expression Blend, and Kaxaml are are interfaces that have a dark color theme. This allows the interface to fade into the background and let the content come alive

Why is it not widely used? I guess it depends on your crowd. For these application it tends to work out great but many people don't like dark interfaces. At my company I created an interface for a very complicated piece of software using a dark UI. It helped to simplify everything and bring attention to the necessary elements at specific times. The problem was, a lot of people complained. "It's too dark," "it doesn't look good on my laptop when I am using in the bright sun" etc. **Some people just hate dark interfaces.**

**Bottom line:** if your applciation is very content driven, esp with visual content, consider a dark interface but be prepared for some opposition.

**Alternative solution:** provide 2 themes, one light and one dark. This is done in Microsoft's Expression Blend (although the light theme looks quite awful, IMO)

Also, it is important to note it is often a bit more difficult to get a dark interface that works well. A little more care must be given to legibility of text on the dark background (i.e. making it bright enough to be legible but not so bright that it is distracting to read.

Answer (score 1):

I have two major issues with dark color schemes:

- Windows (and most other OS themes) are light by default, which makes most other applications light. It is nice when all applications have consistent graphical theme.
- It is much less readable when there is a lot of light around (like sun shining on your screen), and today's glossy screens don't exactly help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Most people (not all) find it harder to read light text on a dark background than dark text on a light background.

It was something that was pointed out to me in school when creating powerpoint presentations, and I noticed the difference when students ignored the recommendation and did a dark background anyways.

Comment: actually it's easier to me to work with applications like Microsoft Expression

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a medical application which is intended to be used in somewhat darker ambients, such as radiology laboratories, so we are using a dark UI similar to Expression Blend Dark, because we noted a light UI is too glaring in those ambients.

The application is supposed to display color images, and subtle intensity changes should be discriminated by medical staff.

A similar thing happens with Photoshop and LightRoom and any other application where color discrimination is important: the user should not be glared, either globally by overall UI brightness, either locally by high contrast in small text, for example.

One reason why we have better visual acuity with light bagckgrounds is that more light makes our pupils compensate it by contracting, thus sharpening focus. On the other hand, dark background makes us adapt to dark, and a crispy glaring light-colored text tend to "overflow" over the background with undesirable results.

There is no absolute counter-indication for using dark backgrounds, it's actually a matter of making the "light" parts have the right brightness so that they are well-seen without being glaring, and maybe having different regions of not-pitch-black, to "buffer" that glaring a little.

Hope this helps.